# "Is there a reason you ask?" vs. "is there a reason you are asking" in context?

Tags: difference, present-continuous, present-simple

Can you please tell me if there is a difference in meaning between *is there a reason you ask?* and *is there a reason you are asking?* In the context below?

> Person A: Are you going to work on Saturday.
>
> Person B: No. Is there a reason **you ask**?/No. Is there a reason **you are asking**?

It seems to me both are perfectly natural in the context, but I can't figure out if there is a difference in meaning.

Comment: I don't see any difference in meaning.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/131750/why-do-you-ask-vs-why-are-you-asking?rq=1

Comment: Any reason one sentence says "***Is** there*" and the other says, "***I sees** there*"? It's easier to compare sentences that are identical other than the bit you're asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that context, both questions have the meaning, "*What is the intent behind asking that particular question?*". The present simple version sounds somewhat more formal to my Canadian ears.

The present continuous version is natural and follows the normal meaning of that verb tense: *action happening in the moment*. The present simple version is also natural, but does not follow the normal meaning of that verb tense *repeated action/ongoing situation in general*. This means the present simple version is an *idiomatic expression* rather than a sentence that naturally emerges from the grammar.